# visual studio 2017 custom configurations

Tags: visual-studio, config

I have a solution with several custom configurations (staging, QA, etc)

Ive added a new project (azure webjob) but the newly added project cant see the custom configurations only the standard Debug & Release.

In the configuration manager the only options I have alongside my new project are debug & release  its not seeing the other custom configs.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Each project and solution has its own list of configurations. The Configuration Manager defines which project configurations will be used for a given solution configuration. So if you add a new project to a solution that already has custom configurations, the project will still only have the default configurations for its type (Debug and Release in this case).

To create new project configurations and associate them with solution configurations of the same name:

1. Right-click your solution in Solution Explorer and open the Configuration Manager.
2. Select your custom solution configuration in *Active solution configuration*.
3. In the *Project contexts* list, find your newly-created project.
4. Expand the *Configuration* drop down and select *New...*.
5. Type the *Name* of the solution configuration.
6. Select *Copy settings from* whichever project configuration makes sense.
7. Click *OK*.